# How to export .mov or .mp4 to HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) files on iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, http-live-streaming

How can I take a `.mov` or `.mp4` video captured on the iPhone device and locally (with Swift) export it to multiple `.ts` (or `fmp4`) and HTTP Live Streaming manifest files?

Rather then creating the HLS streaming files on the backend server, I want to do it locally on the device and then upload all of those files to the server.

I can't find anything in the HLS documentation on how to do that.

Comment: [Git hub library](https://github.com/krad/morsel); [HLS with AVAssetWriter + swifter](https://medium.com/@f_yuki/ios-hls-with-avassetwriter-swifter-37b1ad67af19)

Comment: Is `fmp4` ok? Apple APIs are read-only for transport stream.

Comment: @GordonChilds `fmp4` is also fine. `fmp4` is the future?

Comment: I don't know about `fmp4`s being the future, but at least `AVFoundation` can create them. Can your players play them?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't resist doing a toy `mov/mp4/whatever-AVAssetReader-can-read` -> `HLS` transmuxer using `AVAssetWriter`'s fragmented MPEG-4 feature (`fmp4`).

I'm not sure how HLS-conformant this solution is (you can also switch to `CMAF`, where a similar warning applies) but it played for me in a few players.

**Caveats**:

1. I was forced to split video and audio into separate playlists which seems slightly unusual to me. This was because fmp4 `AVAssetWriter` refuses to do "passthrough" (muxing compressed streams without transcoding) of both audio and video, a baffling Apple API choice
2. The segment durations are the aspirational duration and not the actual duration, so they'll be slightly off and likely wrong for the final segments. I did say it was a toy implementation, still, not bad for 150 LOC.
3. Two deprecated `AVFoundation` methods are used. Maybe I'll fix them.

```
import AVFoundation

class AssetTrackToHLSPlaylist: NSObject {
  let assetWriter: AVAssetWriter
  let input: AVAssetWriterInput
  let destinationDirectory: URL
  let mediaType: String
  let segmentDurationSeconds = 4

  var segmentCount = 0
  var segmentList = ""

  init(input: AVAssetWriterInput, destinationDirectory: URL) {
    assetWriter = AVAssetWriter(contentType: UTType.mpeg4Movie)
    assetWriter.outputFileTypeProfile = .mpeg4AppleHLS // or mpeg4CMAFCompliant!
    assetWriter.preferredOutputSegmentInterval = CMTime(
      value: CMTimeValue(segmentDurationSeconds), timescale: 1)
    assetWriter.initialSegmentStartTime = .zero

    self.input = input
    assetWriter.add(input)

    self.destinationDirectory = destinationDirectory
    self.mediaType = input.mediaType.rawValue

    super.init()
    assetWriter.delegate = self
  }

  func process(reader: AVAssetReaderOutput) {
    let success = assetWriter.startWriting()
    if !success {
      print("fail to start writing \(String(describing: assetWriter.error))")
      abort()
    }

    var started = false
    var inputFinished = false

    while !inputFinished {
      var sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?

      if !inputFinished && input.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
        sampleBuffer = reader.copyNextSampleBuffer()
        if sampleBuffer == nil {
          input.markAsFinished()
          inputFinished = true
        }
      }

      if let sampleBuffer = sampleBuffer {
        if !started {
          let startTime = sampleBuffer.presentationTimeStamp
          assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: startTime)
          started = true
        }
        input.append(sampleBuffer)
      }
    }

    let playlistHeader = """
      #EXTM3U
      #EXT-X-VERSION:3
      #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:\(segmentDurationSeconds)
      #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
      #EXT-X-MAP:URI="\(mediaType)-init.mp4"
      #EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD\n
      """
    let playlist = playlistHeader + segmentList + "#EXT-X-ENDLIST"
    let playlistURL = destinationDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(mediaType).m3u8")

    try? playlist.write(to: playlistURL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
  }

  func writeSegmentFile(data: Data, filename: String) {
    segmentList += "#EXTINF: \(segmentDurationSeconds)\n\(filename)\n"

    try? data.write(to: destinationDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename))
  }
}

extension AssetTrackToHLSPlaylist: AVAssetWriterDelegate {
  func assetWriter(
    _ writer: AVAssetWriter, didOutputSegmentData segmentData: Data, segmentType: AVAssetSegmentType
  ) {
    switch segmentType {

    case .initialization:
      try? segmentData.write(
        to: destinationDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(mediaType)-init.mp4"))
      return
    case .separable:
      writeSegmentFile(data: segmentData, filename: "\(mediaType)-\(segmentCount).m4s")
      segmentCount += 1
    @unknown default:
      return
    }
  }
}

func mov2HLS(movURL: URL, destinationDirectory: URL) {
  let asset = AVURLAsset(url: movURL)

  let reader = try! AVAssetReader(asset: asset)

  let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!
  let videoReader = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: videoTrack, outputSettings: nil)
  reader.add(videoReader)

  let audioTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first!
  let audioReader = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: audioTrack, outputSettings: nil)
  reader.add(audioReader)

  if !reader.startReading() {
    print("FAILED \(reader.status)")
    return
  }

  let videoFormat = videoTrack.formatDescriptions.first! as! CMFormatDescription
  let videoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(
    mediaType: .video, outputSettings: nil, sourceFormatHint: videoFormat)

  let videoM = AssetTrackToHLSPlaylist(input: videoInput, destinationDirectory: destinationDirectory)
  videoM.process(reader: videoReader)

  let audioFormat = audioTrack.formatDescriptions.first! as! CMFormatDescription
  let audioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(
    mediaType: .audio, outputSettings: nil, sourceFormatHint: audioFormat)

  let audioM = AssetTrackToHLSPlaylist(input: audioInput, destinationDirectory: destinationDirectory)
  audioM.process(reader: audioReader)

  let variantPlaylist = """
    #EXTM3U
    #EXT-X-VERSION:3
    #EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="audio",DEFAULT="YES",URI="soun.m3u8"
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AUDIO="audio"
    vide.m3u8
    """

  let variantPlaylistURL = destinationDirectory.appendingPathComponent("playlist.m3u8")

  try? variantPlaylist.write(
    to: variantPlaylistURL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

  print("playlist: \(variantPlaylistURL)")
}
```

Comment: Very interesting! I will take a look myself.

Comment: Actually it's not hard to add exact durations